# How to get the std out of the sub process in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess, output

I need to get the std out of the subprocess in my python code, so I can further process the output in my python code.

I have the following piece of code in python to get the std out but I have an empty value for the output variable.

```
import subprocess
import json
import time


class RunProcess:
    waitTime = 0

    def SetWaitTime(self, waitingTimeInMSec):
        self.waitTime = waitingTimeInMSec

    def Run(self, filePath, arguments):
        if self.waitTime > 0:
            time.sleep(self.waitTime)
        process = subprocess.Popen(filePath + arguments, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)
        output = process.communicate()[0]
        print(output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = RunProcess()
    p.Run("C:\Projects\ATR220-Test\ATR220_Python_Tester\DeviceLoad\SerialReadWrite\srw.exe", " list=PID_0180")
```

But when I run from the windows command prompt, The application gives me the studio out which means there is no issue with the application which I am calling. So I suspect that the issue within my python code.

Output when the exe is run from the Windows command prompt.

```
C:\>C:\Projects\ATR220-Test\ATR220_Python_Tester\DeviceLoad\SerialReadWrite\srw.exe list=PID_0180

C:\>
{
  "list": [
    {
      "availability": "2",
      "name": "COM3",
      "friendlyname": "USB Serial Device (COM3)",
      "pnpdevicepath": "USB\\VID_0DB5&PID_0180&MI_02\\7&8A6C74D&0&0002"
    }
  ],
  "status": {
    "value": 0,
    "description": "ok"
  }
}
```

Comment: "studio out"? I think you may want to say "standard out"

Comment: Thanks and corrected

Comment: Check stderr and process.returncode should be 0. You need to escape backslashes: `p.Run("C:\\Projects\\...")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended to use the `subprocess.run` method instead of manually calling `Popen` directly. This way the output will be like so

```py
output = subprocess.run([filePath, arguments], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output.stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

Also it's not a [good idea to use `shell=True`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations). There are security risks.

Comment: @Raj Nice :) if this did the trick you can mark it as answered

Comment: Oh that's odd :? [this might help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)